# Getting ActiveRecord associations belongs_to through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have models associated with `has_many through`. I am able to get a relationship in one direction but not the other (there is no `belongs_to through` setting)

`Projects` have_many datasets through `taskflows`. `Taskflows` are associated to `datasets` in a join table.

I am able to do `Project.datasets` simply by using the `has_many through` setting. I'd also like to call `dataset.project` to get the associated project of a `dataset` (through `taskflow`).

Is this possible? Many thanks for any help.

I have four models (I've tried the delegate setting but it doesn't seem to work):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3}
  has_many :taskflows
  has_many :datasets, :through => :taskflows
end

class Taskflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :dataset_assignments
  has_many :datasets, :through => :dataset_assignments
end

class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dataset_assignments
  has_many :taskflows, :through => :dataset_assignments
  delegate :project, :to => :taskflows, :has_nil =>true
end

class DatasetAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dataset
  belongs_to :taskflow
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`has_many_through` works both ways.

If you put the has_many_through in reverse in your Dataset Model it should work as you wish.

A good example I use - and I learned on

1. Recipe Model
2. Ingredient Model
3. Component Model

A Recipe has many ingredients through components
An Ingredient has many recipes through components.

In my limited experience with it, your logic makes sense, the has_many through usually flows 'one way' in terms of creation, but in terms of rails it's the same relation type - an ingredient 'has_many' recipes through the components